# Chrome development - chrome.tabs.sendMessage not notifying runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to send a message to newly created / updated tab and receive it there:

```
var tabAction = 'create';      // tabAction equals *create* or *update*

chrome.tabs[tabAction]({
    url:  chrome.extension.getURL('/somepage.htm'),
    active: true
}, function(_tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(_tab.id, {
        message: 'some custom message',
        arg: 'some arg'
    });
});
```

After this call one of the scripts (included in header of the opened page) has to receive this message and do further actions:

```
(function(window, document, jQuery) {
    "use strict";


    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
        // Do stuff
    });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Now my problem:

If tabAction is set to "create" everything works fine - the page is being loaded, the main script sends the message, the extension debugger shows: "Invoked tabs.sendMessage" and "Notified of runtime.onMessage" and the page script does what it has to.

If tabAction is set to "update" - the page is being redirected properly and the main script sends the message as well, but the message is not being sent to the runtime; the debugger just stops at "Invoked tabs.sendMessage".

Why this odd behavior?
Thanks for all the further replies.

Comment: Where are these two lines *"Notified of runtime.onMessage"* and *"Invoked tabs.sendMessage"*? I can't see any debug message like those. Include more relevant code in your question, please.

Comment: These lines are shown in the "Chrome App and Extension Developer Tool" under the realtime behavior tab

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the page has completely loaded when the callback of [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) or [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) is invoked.

If the page does not finish loading when you call `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, then the message is not going to be received by the page (you might see "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." if you check [`chrome.runtime.lastError.message`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError)).

The correct way to solve the problem is to use [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) to detect when the tab has finished loading:

```js
chrome.tabs.update({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('/somepage.htm')
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
            // Now the tab is ready!
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, 'custom message whatever');
        }
    });
});
```

This does not work for `chrome.tabs.create` at the moment because of [crbug.com/411225](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411225). Until that bug is fixed, you have to use the following:

```js
var tabAction = 'create'; // Or update.
chrome.tabs[tabAction]({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('/somepage.htm')
}, function(tab) {
    // Called when the tab is ready.
    var onready = function() {
        onready = function() {}; // Run once.
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
        // Now the tab is ready!
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'custom message whatever');
    };

    // Detect update
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);

    // Detect create (until crbug.com/411225 is fixed).
    chrome.tabs.get(tab.id, function(tab) {
        if (tab.status === 'complete') {
            onready();
        }
    });

    function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            onready();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, but it wasn't firing the event when I  tried to chrome.tabs.get that specific tab, so I just put at the onready(); at the end... I also had to remove onready = function() {}; and chrome.tabs.onUpated.removeListener(listener); because it somehow stopped the evaluation of the rest of the code.
I know, that my current code is some kind messy and hacky, but it's working... :/
Hope google will fix that bug soon.

Comment: btw. is there an other, saver method to pass data to my extension page? Best option would be to invoke a function with parameters on that page

Comment: @IgelHaut The extension messaging system is "safe". You could also try [`chrome.extension.getViews`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) to directly access global objects of your extension page from the background page.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with chrome.tabs.sendMessage in my chrome extension I solved it using the following snippet in manifest.json. Note here the most important things is **"matches": [ "http://*/*"]** in the manifest for content scripts , as testing the code with and without it yields success and error scenarios respectively .

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
  "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "content.js" ],
"all_frames": true,
"matches": [ "http://*/*"]
}],
```